# Android: How to customize income call screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am trying to develop an application that will customize the income call screen.
I understood that it is impossible to customize or to change the exiting income screen, Is it right?

If the answer is no than how?

If the answer is yes than I want to know how to add screen above the income call screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps if your app handles [the ACTION_ANSWER intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER), you could display whatever screen you like. I don't think this will enable you to customize the existing screen, just replace it with your own.

For your app to handle intents you have to add intent filters to the app manifest file. This is fully described in [the Intent class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Here is a quick sample on how you could handle the ACTION_ANSWER intent:

```
     <activity class=".MyCustomCallActivity"
               android:label="@string/mycustomcall_title">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
         </intent-filter>

         ...
     </activity>
```

Comment: thanks. but can you please elaborate on how to use the ACTION_ANSWER please

Comment: that's for you to read...
in any case, once u listen to any intent you just get your activity being called as usual just not for launcher event but for another event, you can get any parameters that were sent in the call even by taking them off the Intent object you can retrieve by using getIntent in onCreate or any other method in your activity.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove the LAUNCHER category, it is not required to handle the ANSWER intent I believe.