# Android: Customize Calling Screen

Tags: android

Anybody knows how to Customize Calling Screen for incoming and outgoing calls?

Any sample code would be of great help.

Comment: 11 questions and none of the accepted. Improve that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518587/android-how-to-customize-income-call-screen