# allow my intent /app to take over the incoming call screen android

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an app that will run when the phone rings but NOT
answer the incoming call.  The app would have an answer button that
when pressed would perform the regular call answer action

I put all permissions

I know WhitePages handles this

Answer (score 0):

ACTION_ANSWER intent could be used to handle an incoming phone call.
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518587/android-how-to-customize-income-call-screen). Hope this would help.