# How to create a custom call receiving application?

Tags: android-intent, android

Is it possible to develop an application with our own UI that receives phone call  instead of the default one?

Comment: there are some app which just changes the way call receive only but rest is done by native..

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4518587/940096)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some app which just changes the way call receive only but rest is done by native

http://www.appsbeyond.com/apps/my-call-screens

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lowveld.ucs&hl=en

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androminigsm.fscifree&hl=en

http://www.xda-developers.com/android/change-your-call-screen-with-ultimate-call-screen-hd/

Comment: Found this post very useful to get some idea.