# Android Modifying in-call screen via AOSP

Tags: android, customization, telephony

I've read elsewhere that 
“Developers cant customize the in-call screen because of security concerns”

So, I am trying to understand the functionality of the in-call screen at the source level.

Can any Android devs, especially those that have created their own custom ROMs, tell me which specific classes in the AOSP are responsible for both display and functionality of this screen?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the source:(from the horse's mouth):
https://code.google.com/p/incomingcallplus/source/checkout
Esp. the BETA Version 0.8.0

By the way, if you are interested in some R&D, I have worked towards this so I know we can access PhoneStateListener and get the status of a call for off the hook, idle and ringing.
https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

Also,
[Android: How to customize income call screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518587/android-how-to-customize-income-call-screen)

Comment: Thanks for the info. So in beta and on code.google.com but not open source?

Comment: They must be reaching that level of abstraction where a call like set content view would customize layouts of the incoming call time too :)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work on Nexus5 running KitKat. On incoming call the incoming call screen still appears.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late but right now Android support for custom in-call screen by implementing InCallService. The application needs to be set as the default dialer to make it work. For more info https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html

Comment: too add to this, see these answers for exact steps one needs to take https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835987/1916449 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856583/1916449