# InCallService - Not working in Android Nougat

Tags: android, phone-call, android-7.0-nougat, in-call

I used [InCallService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html) to replace default call service,
It is working fine in Android 6 (Marshmallow).

But, in Samsung S8 with Android Nougat (version 7.0) not working.
Doesn't get any call back of `InCallService`.

Do I need any additional permissions for Android Nougat to access `InCallService`?

Comment: How did you manage to get it to work in Android 6? I've tried everything and i can't seem to be able to make it work.

Comment: @Siri0S check these out https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835987/1916449 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856583/1916449 I'm curious to know if that sample app would work on the Samsung S8