# When a call arrives, the onCallAdded(Call call) method of InCallService is not called while main thread is still running

Tags: android, kotlin, telecommunication

#### What solution I am looking for

How to make onCallAdded(Call call) method of InCallService called every time when I make call in the main thread ( using #repeat for cycling).

#### Background

I'm writing a small Android auto test APP to automatically make calls then do web browsing...etc for 10 cycles.

My code is based on this article : [Answer incoming call using android.telecom and InCallService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767460/answer-incoming-call-using-android-telecom-and-incallservice)

#### How it is working

1. Here is the MainActivity : Start to make call to $autoCallNumber repeatedly When I click button(autoCall).

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.telecom.TelecomManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.PermissionChecker
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_call.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_dialer.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "${javaClass.simpleName} Wynne"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        offerReplacingDefaultDialer()

        autoCall.setOnClickListener {
            repeat(2) { i ->
                makeCall()
                Log.d(TAG,"We are on the ${i + 1}. loop")
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            }
        }

    }

    private fun makeCall() {
        if (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            var User: GeneralSettings = applicationContext as GeneralSettings

            User.ongoingCalltype = "MO"
            val uri = "tel:${User.autoCallNumber}".toUri()
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri))

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
                DialerActivity.REQUEST_PERMISSION
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == DialerActivity.REQUEST_PERMISSION && PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED in grantResults) {
            makeCall()
        }
    }

    private fun offerReplacingDefaultDialer() {
        if (getSystemService(TelecomManager::class.java).defaultDialerPackage != packageName) {
            Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)
                .putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
                .let(::startActivity)
        }
    }
}
```

2. Here is the Object : Ongoingcall (for me to handle answer or hangup)

```
package com.github.arekolek.phone

import android.telecom.Call
import android.telecom.VideoProfile
import android.util.Log
import io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject
import timber.log.Timber

object OngoingCall {
    val state: BehaviorSubject<Int> = BehaviorSubject.create() 
    private val TAG = "${javaClass.simpleName} Wynne"

    private val callback = object : Call.Callback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(call: Call, newState: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG,"${call.toString()}")
            state.onNext(newState) 
            Log.d(TAG,"New state : $newState")

        }
    }

    var call: Call? = null
        set(value) {

            field?.unregisterCallback(callback)
            value?.let {
                it.registerCallback(callback)
                state.onNext(it.state)

            }

            field = value
        }

    fun answer() {
        call!!.answer(VideoProfile.STATE_AUDIO_ONLY)
    }

    fun hangup() {
        call!!.disconnect()
    }
}
```

3. Here is the CallService (Rewrite onCallAdded/ onCallRemoved of InCallService to handling activities when call arrives/ remove)

```
package com.github.arekolek.phone

import android.telecom.Call
import android.telecom.InCallService
import android.util.Log

class CallService : InCallService() {
    private val TAG = "${javaClass.simpleName} Wynne"

    override fun onCallAdded(call: Call) {
        OngoingCall.call = call 
        try {
            CallActivity.start(this, call)
            Log.d(TAG,"Start Call Activity")
        }
        catch ( e : Exception ) {
            Log.d(TAG,"$e")
        }

    }

    override fun onCallRemoved(call: Call) {
        OngoingCall.call = null 
    }
}
```

4. Here is Call Activity (update call info on UI and hangup unknown call...etc)

```
package com.github.arekolek.phone

import android.R.id.button1
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.telecom.Call
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import io.reactivex.rxkotlin.addTo
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_call.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


class CallActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName

    private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

    private lateinit var ongoingCallNumber: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call)
        ongoingCallNumber = intent.data.schemeSpecificPart
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        var User: GeneralSettings = applicationContext as GeneralSettings

        OngoingCall.state
            .subscribe(::updateUi)
            .addTo(disposables)

        OngoingCall.state
            .filter { it == Call.STATE_DISCONNECTED }
            .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .firstElement()
            .subscribe { finish() }
            .addTo(disposables)

        if (User.ongoingCalltype == "MO") {
            Handler().postDelayed(Runnable { hangup.performClick() }, 5000)
            Log.d(TAG, "Wynne : End MO call after 5 second")
            User.ongoingCalltype = ""

        } else if (ongoingCallNumber == User.autoAnswerNumber) {
            Handler().post(Runnable { answer.performClick() })
            Log.d(TAG, "Wynne : Answer incoming call ${User.autoAnswerNumber} ")
        }
        else{
            Handler().post(Runnable { hangup.performClick() })
            Log.d(TAG, "Wynne : End Unknown incoming call $ongoingCallNumber ")

        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun updateUi(state: Int) {
        callInfo.text = "${state.asString().toLowerCase().capitalize()}\n$ongoingCallNumber"

        answer.isVisible = state == Call.STATE_RINGING
        hangup.isVisible = state in listOf(
            Call.STATE_DIALING,
            Call.STATE_RINGING,
            Call.STATE_ACTIVE
        )
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        disposables.clear()
    }

    companion object {
        fun start(context: Context, call: Call) {
            Intent(context, CallActivity::class.java)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                .setData(call.details.handle)
                .let(context::startActivity)
        }
    }
}
```

5. Here is the AndroidManifest (Bind .CallService (re-written InCallService))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.github.arekolek.phone"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:name=".GeneralSettings"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Handle links from other applications -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <!-- Populate the system chooser -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- Handle links in browsers -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".CallService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI"
                android:value="true"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.InCallService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".CallActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

6. Here is GeneralSettings (Global Variables)

```
package com.github.arekolek.phone

import android.app.Application

class GeneralSettings : Application() {
    val autoCallNumber: String = "0988102544"
    var ongoingCalltype: String = ""
    val autoAnswerNumber: String = "0905112980"

}
```

#### What is the problem then

onCallAdded() of CallService supposed to be called after makeCall() each cycle in #repeat.

However, based on the debug message, I assume that 
the onCallAdded() of CallService is not called until autoCall.setOnClickListener completed.

Here is the Debug message

```
16:52:24.859 D/MainActivity Wynne: We are on the 1. loop
16:52:29.895 D/MainActivity Wynne: We are on the 2. loop
16:52:35.041 D/CallService Wynne: Start Call Activity
16:52:35.048 D/CallService Wynne: Start Call Activity
16:52:35.116 D/CallActivity: Wynne : End MO call after 5 second
16:52:40.161 D/OngoingCall Wynne: New state : 10
16:52:40.419 D/OngoingCall Wynne: New state : 7
16:52:41.551 D/CallActivity: Wynne : End Unknown incoming call 0988102544
```

Can somebody tell me:

How to make onCallAdded() of CallService called every time when I run makeCall() in the main thread?  so that I can disconnect the call before the next cycle.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are declaring `IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI=true` in metadata you need to set your application as the default dialer as well.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI"
    android:value="true"
/>
```

You can do it with the following ADB command:

`adb shell telecom set-default-dialer $your_package_name`

The quote from docs is below:

> METADATA_IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI
> A boolean meta-data value indicating
> whether an InCallService implements an in-call user interface. Dialer
> implementations (see getDefaultDialerPackage()) which would also like
> to replace the in-call interface should set this meta-data to true in
> the manifest registration of their InCallService.

[Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#METADATA_IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI)