# Trying to redirect incoming call to custom made UI in android

Tags: java, android, redirect, screen, incoming-call

I'm trying to redirect incoming calls on a custom made UI instead of default Android screen.
I have tried doing it using many ways like using **CallScreeningService** or **InCallService** but still not able to figure out the solution.
Can anyone **provide a small sample working solution**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Answer incoming call using android.telecom and InCallService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767460/answer-incoming-call-using-android-telecom-and-incallservice)

Comment: Yes @leRobot it does solve my question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [arekolek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916449/arekolek) provided an [answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856583/1103974) with his own source sample at the end.

I verified it working back when he posted it, and should still work on current Android versions. Hope that helps, I would suggest providing feedback to there if it does.