# Replacing default Phone app on Android 6 and 7 with InCallService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

Android API level 23 added [`InCallService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html) to **provide the user-interface for managing phone calls**. The documentation provides an example manifest registration but I couldn't get it to work. The app compiles fine but Default Apps in settings doesn't show my app.

The only place I found any information about the subject was [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861910/replacing-in-call-app) that was closed a year ago. Comment on that question proposed to add `android.intent.action.DIAL` activity but that didn't help me either. I have tried various combinations of other intent's too (`android.intent.action.CALL_DIAL` and `android.intent.action.ANSWER`) in my activity.

Are there any working examples of code needed to replace the phone app? Do the classes need to provide some working methods for the app to show?

Comment: I have an application with 'InCallService' , it is working fin e in android 6. But, I run on Android 7 it is not getting the InCallService call backs. Do you have any idea ? . I have posted a question few days ago regarding this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079210/incallservice-not-working-in-android-nougat , didn't get any reply.

Comment: @VineeshTP How did you manage to make it work on Android 6? Please share the solution if you can

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html,  Use the Android documentation code  it self.  Which is mentioned in the first paragraph itself.  <service android:name="your.package.YourInCallServiceImplementation"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE">
      <meta-data android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.telecom.InCallService"/>
      </intent-filter>
 </service>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The app compiles fine but Default Apps in settings doesn't show my app.

To have your app listed as a Phone app, you must have an activity with at least those intent filters (to handle both cases mentioned in documentation of [ACTION_DIAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL), also mentioned in [DefaultDialerManager hidden class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telecomm/java/android/telecom/DefaultDialerManager.java#144)):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
</intent-filter>
```

And to be honest, that's a bit counterintuitive, because setting the default Phone app is separate from setting a default Dialer – the former controls only the ongoing call UI, while the latter controls only the dialing UI.

The above minimum can be improved a bit, to allow setting your dialer as a default, and launching from web browser, by using these intent filters instead:

```
<intent-filter>
    <!-- Handle links from other applications -->
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <!-- Populate the system chooser -->
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <!-- Handle links in browsers -->
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The [Dialer app in AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/nougat-release/AndroidManifest.xml#79) has even more filters declared.

You can make it easier for the user to set your app as the default Phone app with the help from `TelecomManager`:

```
if (getSystemService(TelecomManager::class.java).defaultDialerPackage != packageName) {
    Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)
            .putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
            .let(::startActivity)
}
```

This will show a dialog similar to this:

[image: change default dialer dialog]

Refer to [Answer incoming call using android.telecom and InCallService](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41767460/1916449) for what you need to do to actually handle the calls themselves.

Here's the code for an app that implements the minimum needed to handle dialing, and accepting/rejecting/ending calls in its own UI:

https://github.com/arekolek/simple-phone

Comment: Can you tell please how i can reject incoming call using this method? it vibrates a little bit before rejecting by using call.reject() method but i don't want that behavior.

Comment: @MateenChaudhry I encourage you to post that as a separate question

Comment: Here is the question.
if you can answer please answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130348/reject-call-silently-using-incallservice/52130709?noredirect=1#comment91219240_52130709

Comment: its not working in MIUI xiomi device. I think its work only Native Android OS not custom ROM.

Comment: That's how I managed to set my app as default phone app: `if (getSystemService(TelecomManager.class).getDefaultDialerPackage() != getPackageName()) {
            Intent ChangeDialer = new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER);
            ChangeDialer.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
            startActivity(ChangeDialer);
        }`

Comment: @arekolek, the app you recommended works perfectly. But I am facing difficulties to pass object to **CallActivity**. I appreciate if you could help me. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55620683/4300670

Comment: is there a java version of this project?

Comment: @user13267 I was made aware of [one such Java fork](https://github.com/Abror96/CustomPhoneDialer), I can see it could be improved, but I've been told that it works

Comment: Were you able to achieve enabling outspeaker i tried but its not working through setAudioRoute(int route) anyhelp is appreciated?

Comment: TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER is no longer supported since Q, please use android.app.role.RoleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(String) with android.app.role.RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER instead  Could you, please, update your simple-phone app.