# Reject call silently using InCallService

Tags: android

i am trying to reject an incoming call using `InCallService`by making my app default dialer app.It is rejecting call fine but the problem is if the mobile is on vibration mode its vibrate it little bit I have explored the class but i couldn't find any method to silent the ringer here is my code how i implemented `InCallService` service

```
    public class myService extends InCallService {

    private String TAG="myService";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onBind");
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onUnbind");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

    public myService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallAudioStateChanged(CallAudioState audioState) {

        super.onCallAudioStateChanged(audioState);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCallAudioStateChanged");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBringToForeground(boolean showDialpad) {
        super.onBringToForeground(showDialpad);
        Log.d(TAG,"onBringToForeground");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
        super.onCallAdded(call);

        call.reject(false,"ds");

    }  
}
```

can you please tell how can I reject call silently?

Answer (score 1):

If you're making your app the default dialer app, try implementing the [CallScreeningService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService) API.  That API will allow you to intercept and block calls prior to the system starting ringing.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to change the approach.

**Step 1 :** Create a broadcast receiver

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        rejectCall();
    }

    public void rejectCall() {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
                if (telecomManager != null) {
                    telecomManager.endCall();
                }
            } else {
                rejectCallViaTelephonyManager();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "call ended successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void rejectCallViaTelephonyManager() {
        ITelephony telephonyService = getTelephonyService(context);
        if (telephonyService != null) {
            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
            telephonyService.endCall();
        }
    }

    private ITelephony getTelephonyService(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            return (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: Add this receiver to your manifest file

```
<receiver
    android:name=".CallReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Step 3:** You need to add permission as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: we already did this. it does not work on andoid P. and second it also vibrate the phone a little bit.

Comment: It does work, `TelecomManager` is specially for devices `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O`. For the vibration issue you need to look Notification Service.