# Android Studio: Pass parcelable data to call service (Phone Call App)

Tags: android, parcelable, android-phone-call

I am using [this app](https://github.com/Abror96/CustomPhoneDialer) as a framework and trying to pass an object to my own UI Phone Call .

But when I try to put my object into `myAdapter`:

`Call.putExtra("itemObject", items.get(position));`

I get a `BadParcelableException` error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.server.telecom/com.android.server.telecom.components.UserCallActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.example.aliton.customphonecall.itemObject
```

**Question**: How do I pass my object to `CallActivity`?

In order to make it a bit more clear, I want to pass my object via a `Button` in `myAdapter`.

As can be seen below, the `Button` track first goes from `myAdapter` to `CallService` and inside `CallService` is called `CallActivity`.

Then I thought I could pass my object to `CallService` and pass again my object to `CallActivity`.

```
I/debinf Adapter: Requesting Call
I/debinf CallService: onCallAdded
I/debinf OngoingCall: call.getState() is 9
I/debinf CallService: starting CallActivity
I/debinf CallActivity: onCreate
I/debinf OngoingCall: state is 1
I/debinf OngoingCall: state is 4
```

Here is `myAdapter`:

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<itemObject> items;
    private Context context;

    public myAdapter(ArrayList<itemObject> items, Context context) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_call, parent, false);

        TextView mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TextView mId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
        final TextView mPhone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_phone);
        ImageButton mCall = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.item_call);

        mName.setText(items.get(position).getName());
        mId.setText(items.get(position).getId());
        mPhone.setText(items.get(position).getPhone());

        mCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:"+mPhone.getText().toString().trim());
                Intent Call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
                Call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Call.putExtra("itemObject", items.get(position));
                Log.i("debinf Adapter", "Requesting Call");
                context.startActivity(Call);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is my `CallService`:

```
public class CallService extends InCallService {

    @Override
    public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
        super.onCallAdded(call);

        Log.i("debinf CallService", "onCallAdded");
        new OngoingCallObject().setCall(call);

        Log.i("debinf CallService", "starting CallActivity");
        Intent CallAct = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class);
        CallAct.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        CallAct.setData(call.getDetails().getHandle());
        startActivity(CallAct);

        //CallActivity.start(this, call);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallRemoved(Call call) {
        super.onCallRemoved(call);
        Log.i("debinf CallService", "onCallRemoved");
        new OngoingCallObject().setCall(null);
    }

}
```

I want to use my object to fill the `TextView` on the upper left part of `CallActivity`.

[image: PhoneCall2]

Here is `DialerAcitivity` image.

[image: PhoneCall1]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your and my same problem ? I would like to pass an easy string parameter to the Call.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I have a correct answer but it's not what you expect.
It's not impossible to pass custom parameters to Intent.ACTION_CALL because the real call to the Phone App is created by the system that ignores all custom parameters (extra in your Intent.ACTION_CALL call).