# How to change default dialer application in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source, android-automotive, custom-rom

I am creating one custom dialer application in AOSP through Android.mk and I have also added following lines in my Android.mk file,

LOCAL_MODULE_NAME := MyDialer
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES :- Dialer

and building custom dialer application through this, but when I boot for the first time in settings application MyDialer is not selected by default, it will be none first then after user selects MyDialer manually then it will work, How should we set MyDialer as default dialer in system at the build time itself and avoid manual selection?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask in your application on first run to make it default app.

Check Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838222/replacing-default-phone-app-on-android-6-and-7-with-incallservice)

[Replacing default Phone app on Android 6 and 7 with InCallService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838222/replacing-default-phone-app-on-android-6-and-7-with-incallservice)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a config.xml file in the Android build system for default dialer: `packages/services/Telecomm/res/values/config.xml`. Pls try to modify below items to point to your own dialer application:

```
<!-- Package name for the default in-call UI and dialer [DO NOT TRANSLATE] -->
<string name="ui_default_package" translatable="false">com.android.dialer</string>

<!-- Class name for the default in-call UI Service [DO NOT TRANSLATE] -->
<string name="incall_default_class" translatable="false">com.android.incallui.InCallServiceImpl</string>

<!-- Class name for the default main dialer activity [DO NOT TRANSLATE] -->
<string name="dialer_default_class" translatable="false">com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity</string>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution for aosp android-11 for google pixel 4xl (coral) device but it's not working. There is no error but the default dialer app were not set. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the update answer for the same question. 
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72007752/2079023